# rate based on the few condition

Tags: python, pandas

I want add rate based on the conditions in few columns
if `A > 30` +1 and `B > 50` +1 and `C > 80` +1, D doesn't matter,
for example i have a matrix (dataframe):

```
    A   B   C   D
0  21  32  84  43  # 0 + 0 + 1
1  79  29  42  63  # 1 + 0 + 0
2  31  38   6  52  # 1 + 0 + 0
3  92  54  79  75  # 1 + 1 + 0
4   9  14  87  85  # 0 + 0 + 1
```

what i try:

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: import pandas as pd
In [36]: df = pd.DataFrame(
np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5, 4)),
columns=list('ABCD')
)
In [36]: df
Out[36]: 
    A   B   C   D
0  21  32  84  43
1  79  29  42  63
2  31  38   6  52
3  92  54  79  75
4   9  14  87  8
```

- create series (`df['A'] > 30`)
- concat it to the frame
- and sum rows

```py
In [37]: df['R'] = pd.concat(
[(df['A'] > 30), (df['B'] > 50), (df['C'] > 80)], axis=1
).sum(axis=1)
In [38]: df
Out[38]: 
    A   B   C   D  R
0  21  32  84  43  1
1  79  29  42  63  1
2  31  38   6  52  1
3  92  54  79  75  2
4   9  14  87  85  1
```

And result as i expected, but maybe there are more simple way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
df['R'] = (df.iloc[:,:3]>[30, 50, 80]).sum(axis=1)
```

the same solution using column names

```
df['R'] = (df[['A','B','C']]>[30, 50, 80]).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: very nice, could you pleas provide answer where columns are not one by one?

Comment: Do you mean if columns are not adjacent or serially ordered? For example if you want conditions to apply to columns D,A,C instead:
df['R'] = (df.iloc[:,[3,0,2]]>[30, 50, 80]).sum(axis=1)

Comment: # If you use column names then: 
df['R'] = (df[['A','B','C']]>[30, 50, 80]).sum(axis=1)

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
df["R"] = (
    (df["A"] > 30).astype(int) +
    (df["B"] > 50).astype(int) +
    (df["C"] > 80).astype(int)
)
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: @Mercury provide very short and good answer, so sorry i marked him as the answer, your solution still very readable, thank you!

Comment: It's OK, I agree that their answer is better :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this. Not sure if it is any better.

```
>>> df
    A   B   C   D
0   8  47  95  52
1  90  84  39  80
2  15  52  37  79
3  99  24  76   5
4  93   4  97   0
```

---

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: int(x[0] > 30) + int(x[1] > 50) + int(x[2] > 80) , axis=1)
0    1
1    2
2    1
3    1
4    2
dtype: int64
```

---

```
>>> df.agg(lambda x: int(x[0] > 30) + int(x[1] > 50) + int(x[2] > 80) , axis=1)
0    1
1    2
2    1
3    1
4    2
dtype: int64
```